# Component disappears when another component is added and the page was not saved

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

We're having an issue where a user adds a component to a page, and then adds another component to the first component. But when they add the second component the page reloads and since the content wasn't saved after the first component was added neither component shows after the page reloads.

Having the content editor save between the two adds solves the issue, however I'd like to stream line the editing experience by saving the layout details when the first component is added, however I'm having trouble finding the correct pipeline to use to do that. Does anyone have experience with something like this?

Comment: Do you want to really save between the 2 adds, because then it saves everything not only presentation details. Maybe the users don't want to save it. I would suggest to investigate what's is the issue there, Did you check the log files? Or any exceptions while debuging?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I have seen something like this before; but I'm not sure if it's going to be the same issue I had, which was due to a customisation I added.  Other than creation of the datasource item itself, does the process of adding the second rendering cause the creation of any other items (e.g folders during a pipeline processor)?

Comment: Please check the placeholders are properly added in that item

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before on older versions of Sitecore. It is recommended to save as you go. When training clients I often advise my clients to ctr+S as they go.